# deletechars parameter in genfromtxt not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am working with some csv that have single quotes surrounding the values of the first column. I need to remove them in order to do further comparisons against other stuff. So I really need to perform this replacement efficiently.

I am using genfromtxt with deletechars="'" but single quotes are kept anyway.

A sample code is here

```
import numpy as np
file_name='myCSV.csv'
np.genfromtxt(file_name,delimiter=',',usecols=0,dtype='S30',skip_header=1,deletechars="'")
```

What I have : `'myValue'`

What I want : `myValue`

What I get : `'myValue'` the same as not using deletechars

**EDIT**

```
converters={0:lambda x: x.replace('\'','')}
```

solves my problem but why deletechars does not work remains a mystery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> deletechars : str, optional
>     A string combining invalid characters that must be deleted from the
>     names.
> ```

It deletes these chars from the NAMES - field or column names, not the row values.  Note that a number of other parameters also deal with the names.