# In numpy genfromtxt, missing_values, filling_values, excludelist, deletechars and replace_space are not working properly

Tags: python, numpy

This is my test.csv file, where "A 1" and "A+2" are headers:

```
A 1,A+2
test&     ,1
skip,
#,
N/A,NA
```

This is my Jupyter code:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", 
                          delimiter = ',',
                          dtype = str,
                          comments = '#',
                          converters = None,
                          missing_values='NA', 
                          filling_values=np.nan,
                          excludelist = ['skip'],
                          deletechars = " !#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^{|}~",
                          replace_space = '_',
                          autostrip = True
                         )
print(test)
```

This is my output:

```
[['A 1' 'A+2']
 ['test&' '1']
 ['skip' '']
 ['N/A' 'NA']]
```

Why is it not this output:

```
[['A_1' 'A2']
 ['test' '1']
 ['NA' nan]]
```

What is the correct way to use missing_values, filling_values, excludelist, deletechars and replace_space?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30291887/8508004) covers your 'deletechars' question. Upshot is it only applies to column names, not the row values.

Comment: If the documented parameter refers to `name`, `field names` or even `variable name`, it applies to column names, which you aren't using.  That basically leaves the filling/missing values to decipher.  The docs don't gives examples. I haven't had good luck with those in previous SO.

Comment: I explored missing/fiilling values in previous SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298097/numpy-genfromtxt-missing-data-vs-bad-data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317590/numpy-genfromtxt-how-to-detect-bad-int-input-values.  Those were for float and int dtypes.  I'm not sure what's happening with a str dtype.

Comment: We need to read the fuller documentation at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

Answer (score 0):

First a barebones read:

```
In [249]: txt="""A 1,A+2
     ...: test&     ,1
     ...: skip,
     ...: #,
     ...: N/A,NA"""

In [250]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', dtype=str)
Out[250]: 
array([['A 1', 'A+2'],
       ['test&     ', '1'],
       ['skip', ''],
       ['N/A', 'NA']], dtype='<U10')
```

With `usemask` and a list of missing values (seems to need one per column):

```
In [251]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', autostrip=False, dtype=str, missing_values=['N/A','NA'],usemask=True)
Out[251]: 
masked_array(
  data=[['A 1', 'A+2'],
        ['test&     ', '1'],
        ['skip', --],
        [--, --]],
  mask=[[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [ True,  True]],
  fill_value='N/A',
  dtype='<U10')

In [253]: _251.filled()
Out[253]: 
array([['A 1', 'A+2'],
       ['test&     ', '1'],
       ['skip', 'N/A'],
       ['N/A', 'N/A']], dtype='<U10')
```

I'm not sure what's going on with filling_values.

The source code for `genfromtxt` is mostly python, but quite complex, including the parts dealing with missing/filling values.

You might have more success with the `pandas` reader; it seems to handle missing values more gracefully.

In recent numpy versions, `np.loadtxt` has been rewritten to be faster.  But it doesn't handle missing values.