# In numpy genfromtxt, how to use `names = True`?

Tags: python, numpy

This is a follow up question to my previous question:

[In numpy genfromtxt, missing_values, filling_values, excludelist, deletechars and replace_space are not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053670/in-numpy-genfromtxt-missing-values-filling-values-excludelist-deletechars-an)

This is my test.csv file, where "A 1" and "A+2" are headers:

```
A 1,A+2
test&     ,1
skip,
#,
N/A,NA
```

With this Jupyter code:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", 
                          delimiter = ',',
                          dtype = str,
                          names = None
                         )
test
```

I get this output:

```
array([['A 1', 'A+2'],
       ['test&     ', '1'],
       ['skip', ''],
       ['N/A', 'NA']], dtype='<U10')
```

Here `dtype='<U10'` is reasonable, because there are 10 characters in `'test&     '`.

But when I change `names = None` to `names = True`, I get this output.  I understand that the headers `A 1` and `A+2` have been changed to `A_1` and `A2`.  But why is it `'<U'`?

```
array([('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')], dtype=[('A_1', '<U'), ('A2', '<U')])
```

Comment: Use `dtype=None`

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks, but I find it strange that `dtype = str` cannot auto-identify the correct Unicode string length... and when I included the parameter `excludelist = ['skip'],` to `genfromtxt`, the `'skip'` value still appeared in my output data... `genfromtxt` seems to be a nightmare to use.

Comment: `str` does not work when creating a structured array.  Either let it deduce the dtype or specify the string length.  I haven't paid attention to the `exclude` parameter.

Comment: `excludelist` applies to **names**. Have you read the linked fuller documentation page? 
 https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html.  I just noticed that, and need to spend more time on it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the ipython session I used for your previous question, I can create a structured array with `names` and `dtype=None`.  That's something I often recommend.

```
In [272]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', autostrip=True,  missing_values={0:'N/A',1:'NA'},names=True,dtype=None, filling_values={0:'nan',1:'-999'}, encoding=True)
Out[272]: 
array([('test&',    1), ('skip', -999), ('N/A', -999)],
      dtype=[('A_1', '<U5'), ('A2', '<i8')])
```

With `None`, it deduces the column dtype, in this case `int` for the second.  I got the missing/filling values to work for this  column.  It still doesn't work with the string column.  That's consistent with previous attempts I linked in your previous question.  Missing/filling works for numeric columns.

I can specify column dtype by column

```
In [273]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', autostrip=True,  names=True,dtype=['U10','U10'])
Out[273]: 
array([('test&', '1'), ('skip', ''), ('N/A', 'NA')],
      dtype=[('A_1', '<U10'), ('A2', '<U10')])
```

We have seen in other SO that `np.array(..., dtype=str)` works, but `np.array(...., dtype=[('x',str), ...])` does not.  In the first case `np.array` will deduce the needed string length from all data.  In the second, it uses the `dtype` to create a "empty" array, and then fills it.  It cannot deduce the necessary string length for structured arrays.  You have to spell that out.

While it's convenient to load csv files as structured arrays, you really need to spend some time learning about that type of array - what is meant by `field`, and field names and dtypes.  It that's too much, I suggest using `pandas` instead.

All the `names` parameters have to do with sanitizing field names derived from the file (see the linked documentation).  If you create a `recarray` from a structured array, fields can be accessed as attributes.  But python has restrictions on what a valid attribute name looks like (same as for variable names).  I suspect those restrictions also apply to column names of pandas dataframes.

`recarrays` don't get used as much now that `pandas` is available.  `pandas` developers have spent more time dealing with things like missing values.

Let me repeat the link to fuller documentation

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

### `str` in dtype

```
In [275]: np.array(['one','two','three'],dtype=str)
Out[275]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='<U5')

In [276]: np.array([('one'),('two'),('three')],dtype=[('x',str)])
Out[276]: array([('',), ('',), ('',)], dtype=[('x', '<U')])

In [277]: np.array([('one'),('two'),('three')],dtype=[('x','U10')])
Out[277]: array([('one',), ('two',), ('three',)], dtype=[('x', '<U10')])
```

### skip lines

It does not have, as far as I can tell, a means of skipping lines based on content - other than the `comment` character(s?).  But it accepts input from anything that can feed it lines, an open file, a file passed through a filter script, or as in my demos a list of strings.

For example I can filter out strings that contain 'skip':

```
In [281]: [line for line in txt.splitlines() if not 'skip' in line]
Out[281]: ['A 1,A+2', 'test&     ,1', '#,', 'N/A,NA']

In [283]: np.genfromtxt((line for line in txt.splitlines() if not 'skip' in line), delimiter=',',dtype=str)
Out[283]: 
array([['A 1', 'A+2'],
       ['test&     ', '1'],
       ['N/A', 'NA']], dtype='<U10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can go through the docs (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), but i will summerize it here :

< - stands for little-endian ( computers store numbers in binary form, 100101, for dealing with numbers you and i know that the right-most digit is the smallest, and the leftmost digit is the largest, which is the right-to-left way, but computers can do it in the opposite direction, left-to-right, these are called big-endian and little-endian, read more here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

U - stands for unicode ( which is mapping from numbers to characters, because the computer only understands numbers, so when its dealing with string it needs a table to map a number to a character)

10 - the size of U, so U10 together means, 10 unicode characters max, "abcdefghij" , its doing that because i guess your largest text is 'test&     ' which i will assume is 10 characters long.

Comment: Here the issue is why `str` is sufficient in one case but not the other.